# How to add PRE deployment script to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker EC2 instance, custom AMI not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I'm really liking the fact that I'm able to use Docker images pushed into AWS ECR with Elastic Beanstalk. Only thing that has given me a headache is lack of information on how to add pre-deploy hooks into your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance?

If I've understood correctly, .ebextensions scripts run POST deploy so those are not resolving my problem here.

I came up with a solution where I added the script needed to be run at pre deploy phase into the EB EC2 instance manually. More specifically into directory:

**/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre**

Now that script gets executed everytime I deploy new application version into my instance which is exactly what I want. But if load balancer attached to my EB environment launches a new EB instance, it doesn't obviously contain the manually added script and therefore will not be able to run my application.

I also tried to create an AMI from the running EB EC2 container containing my custom pre deploy script but for some reason Docker is unable to start on the new EB instance based on my custom AMI.

eb-activity.log says:

```
[2016-08-29T07:38:36.580Z] INFO  [3887]  - [Initialization/PreInitStage0/PreInitHook/01setup-docker-options.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: Stopping docker: [FAILED]
Starting docker:      ..........[FAILED
(ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Stopping docker: [FAILED]
Starting docker:      ..........[FAILED] (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

if I SSH into the EB instance and try to start the Docker service manually, same result:

```
sudo service docker restart
Stopping docker:                                       [FAILED]
Starting docker:    ..........                         [FAILED]
```

I would highly appreciate if someone could tell me what is the correct way to add PRE DEPLOYMENT script into Elastic Beanstalk, thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE**

I solved the AMI problem by launching new instance from the same AMI that Elastic Beanstalk uses by default (aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2016.03.3.x86_64-docker-hvm-201608240450). I customized that instance by adding my script into **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre** even though **hooks** directory structure:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/
├── appdeploy
│   ├── enact
│   ├── post
│   └── pre
├── configdeploy
│   ├── enact
│   ├── post
│   └── pre
├── postinit
├── preinit
└── restartappserver
    ├── enact
    ├── post
    └── pre
```

isn't present at this fresh instance. The directory structure will be fully generated when the Docker application is deployed and scripts added to that directory structure in advance will be executed.

Even though that solves my problem, I would like to use similar solution as **.ebextensions** provide but is there similar support for other than POST DEPLOY scripts?

Comment: What are you trying to run pre-deploy? Can it be built into the docker image? If your app is dockerized, you shouldn't care what is going on with the VM hosting it.